# Android: send sms after receiving one

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I' writing an app to send phone location after receiving an SMS request. Receiving SMS's works and sending SMS works too. What to do to make it send SMS after receiving one?

MainActivity

```
final static String gpsLocationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
final static String networkLocationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
static String loc;
public LocationManager locationManager;
static TextView messageBox;


public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    messageBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageBox);

    locationManager =
            (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location lastKnownLocation_byGps =
            locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(gpsLocationProvider);
    Location lastKnownLocation_byNetwork =
            locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(networkLocationProvider);

    if (lastKnownLocation_byGps != null) {
        loc = "gps " + lastKnownLocation_byGps.getLatitude();
    }
    if (lastKnownLocation_byNetwork != null) {
        loc = "net lat:" + lastKnownLocation_byNetwork.getLatitude() + " long:" + lastKnownLocation_byNetwork.getLongitude();
    }
}

public static void updateMessageBox(String msg) {
    messageBox.setText(msg);
}
```

Receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

    Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms=new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++){
        sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }

    for(SmsMessage msg:sms){
        MainActivity.updateMessageBox("\nFrom: "+msg.getOriginatingAddress()+"\n"+
                "Message: "+msg.getMessageBody());
    }
}
```

Where to put sendSMS method to send SMS after receiving one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your send sms code statements at the end of onReceive method, because this method executes when you receive a sms.